# Samba symlink to a local windows directory

Tags: windows, samba, symbolic-link, nas

I've just finished moving the majority of my files from my Windows machines, to a new central Ubuntu, ZFS NAS.

Before I made this move, my Windows PC games used to live on a HDD, mounted as G:\ on my primary Windows PC.

As this drive is crazy slow, I used to copy a couple of games that I was playing frequently over to one of that machines NVMe drives, and create a Windows junction pointing at it's new location. That way it'd load much quicker, but I could switch in and out whichever games I'm playing at the time, without the registry getting all messed up, and other headaches.

The problem is, the symlinks aren't visible in the samba share as far as I can see...

I can create a symlink in my share in Ubuntu, to point to the location that it can't actually access... So it looks like:

```
1141802 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   52 Feb 10 20:20 'Red Dead Redemption 2' -> 'A:/Games/Red Dead Redemption 2'
```

But then it's not there when I navigate to my Windows mapped drive.

1. Is what I'm trying to do at all possible?
2. If not, can anyone think of a nice way around this... I want to install games to G:\ in Windows (the mapped samba share), but be able to actually play them off of A:\.

Thanks.

Comment: I dabbled a bit with having 60GB Windows games stored on HDD and then moved to SSD when being played. The Game manufacturer had pretty good instructions for accomplishing the swapping games between SSD and HDD. That said this isn't a Windows support site. Your question littered with `G:\\`` and `A:\\`` instead of `/home/Jack/Games` suggests your question is more about Windows and less about Ubuntu.

Comment: It's about setting up an Ubuntu samba share, that points to a Window directory... All the configuration needs to occur in Ubuntu, which is why I'm asking here. But maybe I'd be better off on serverfault?

Comment: Serverfault is kind of an elite multi-million-dollar-main-frame-mentality. I don't think they delve much into games. Perhaps SuperUser first or in addition to? Who knows though with any luck someone here will answer your question. Wait a bit I guess cause people frown on cross-posting too quickly.

Comment: Games was just an example... It's just a question of, how can I mount a *nix samba share, that, when mounted in Windows, can point to a local windows directory... Maybe I can create a junction in Windows on the mapped drive, thinking about it...

Comment: It's been so long since my DOS days but there is the `map` command? https://www.howtogeek.com/118452/how-to-map-network-drives-from-the-command-prompt-in-windows/

Comment: Yup, that's mapping the samba share to the new drive in Windows. So I have a G:\ drive mounted, that's actually the samba share from my NAS now. So `G:\ -> \\nas\Games`, basically... What doesn't work is that the symlink I created on the NAS, the one that's shown in the question's `ls` output. It's just absent on my Windows machine. I have a feeling it simply isn't possible due to the differences between symlink implementations between NTFS and ZFS. But I'm hoping...

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5120

Comment: @mook765 - It's related, but not the same, and the chosen solution doesn't work for this scenario.

Comment: I think you might be hitting a bug, try this: delete the symlink, create a file in the share, anything will do, now recreate the symlink.

Comment: @RowlandPenny - The share is going the other way... I install an application to `G:\\ `, which is the samba mapped drive (`/nas/games`, on the NAS). Then I move, say, `G:\RDR2`, to, `A:\RDR2` (so it's now on my *local* machine, instead of the samba share. However, there are a lot of registry entries that are required for some Windows executables, so it expects that the game, `RDR2` in this case, to still be installed to `G:\RDR2`, and *not* in, `A:\RDR2`... To get around this, I run `ln -s /nas/games/RDR2 'A:\RDR2'`, which produces the symlink in Ubuntu (shown in my OP), but it isn't shared.